# give some basic idea of jsp-servlet program without NetBean IDE

Tags: jsp, servlets, netbeans

how can i make jsp-servlet program without netbeans IDE? and give me some basic steps to run that program

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to read [Head First Servlets and JSP](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596005405.do), hope this will be a good book for a beginer.

Comment: sir but i want quick solution so i kindly request to u sir plz help me

Comment: can you give me some basic idea sir